# view and animate SVG diagrams in Ruby GTK

Tags: ruby, svg, ruby-gnome2

I'm wondering if it's possible to view and then hopefully animate SVG diagrams in pure Ruby GTK.

I'd prefer to use only the Gtk API. SVG is necessary. Thus I exclude a dedicated games library like Ruby2D or Gosu.

I also found the excellent [Oekaki](https://rubygems.org/gems/oekaki/versions/0.1.7) gem, but SVG is no handled either.

Ruby GTK3 seems to provide a Rsvg gem, but the documentation is sparse concerning its actual use.

Comment: This example show how to view SVG with Ruby/Gtk3. https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome/blob/master/rsvg2/sample/svg-viewer.rb

Comment: Thx. I know this example. However, it is very far from animation, I think. It seems that only Javascript allows for such SVG animation :-(